# I'm wondering why this program won't run, temperature program

Tags: java

I just started programming and am doing pretty well but am not sure why this program has no output.  Any pointers would be great, or what I am missing.  Thank you so much and I'm glad to be a part of this site now.

```
package temperature;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Temperature {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int count;

    double temp, temptotal, average, farenheit, ftotal, ctotal, caverage, faverage;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);


    temp = 0;
    count = 0;

    while( temp <= -100.0){

    System.out.println("Enter Temp in Centigrade or <= -100.0 to quit: ");

    temp = keyboard.nextDouble();
    ctotal = 0;
    ftotal = 0;
    caverage = 0;
    faverage = 0;
    farenheit = (9.0/5.0) * temp + 32.0;
    ctotal += temp;
    ftotal += farenheit;
    count++;


    if (temp <= -100.0){
        caverage = ctotal / count;
        faverage = ftotal /count;
        System.out.print(caverage);
        System.out.print(faverage);
        System.out.print("Average: Centigrade" +caverage);
        System.out.println("Average: Farenheit" +faverage);
    }

    else{
        System.out.print("Temperature: F" +farenheit );
        System.out.println("C " +temp);
    }


    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You never get into your "while" loop because of your initial conditions:

```
temp = 0;
count = 0;

while( temp <= -100.0){
```

temp starts out at 0, which is > -100, so the while loop is skipped and the program ends.

Perhaps you meant

```
while (temp >= - 100.0)
```

Happy coding.

Comment: A trivial debugging effort would have pinpointed this error, so -1.

Comment: @MartinJames You did notice that he said "I just started programming", didn't you?

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop goes `while (temp <= -100)`, but your initial `temp` value is `0`, thus it never enters the loop.

Either set the initial temp value to be `-100`, or instead use a `do {} while(temp<=-100);` structure.